# Saving video to DocumentsDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to improve my self with coding Objective c and I am not good enough to solve this problem. 
I am using the code below to merge video with audio and save the final video to camera roll. The code working perfect but what I need is to save that video to temporary documents, so that I can change or modify the video without saving it every time I do small change.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addBackgroundMusicAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.asset == nil) {
        return;
    }


    NSString *outPutPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];

    NSURL *outPutUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outPutPath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outPutPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outPutPath error:nil];
    }
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    CMTimeRange videoTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.asset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[self.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject];
    [videoTrack insertTimeRange:videoTimeRange ofTrack:videoAssetTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVURLAsset *audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myAudio" ofType:@"mp3"]] options:nil];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *audioAssetTrack = [[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] firstObject];
    [audioTrack insertTimeRange:videoTimeRange ofTrack:audioAssetTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


    // 3.1 - Create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.asset.duration);
    // 3.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videolayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
    UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    CGAffineTransform videoTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
        videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationRight;
        isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
    }
    if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
        videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
        isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
    }
    if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
        videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
    }
    if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
        videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
    }
    [videolayerInstruction setTransform:videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [videolayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:self.asset.duration];

    // 3.3 - Add instructions
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videolayerInstruction,nil];

    AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

    CGSize naturalSize;
    if(isVideoAssetPortrait_){
        naturalSize = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);
    } else {
        naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;
    }

    float renderWidth, renderHeight;
    renderWidth = naturalSize.width;
    renderHeight = naturalSize.height;
    mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(renderWidth, renderHeight);
    mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
    mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);


    AVAssetExportSession * assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    assetExport.outputURL = outPutUrl;
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    assetExport.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
    [assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self exportDidFinish:assetExport];
        });
    }];
}
```

And her is where I export the video to the camera roll:

```
- (void)exportDidFinish:(AVAssetExportSession*)session {
    if (session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
        NSURL *outputURL = session.outputURL;
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL]) {
            [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (error) {
                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Video Saving Failed"
                                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alert show];
                    } else {
                        AVPlayerItem * playeritem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:outputURL];
                        [_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playeritem];
                        [_player play];

                    }
                });
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, I do not need to save the video to the camera roll, I just need to save it Temporary. Also I need to load that video when I press another button. Saving that video and load it again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Following code:

```
 NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:outputURL];
    if (videoData) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];
        // Create folder if needed
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

        NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.mp4"];
        if ([videoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
            // yeah - file written
        } else {
            // oops - file not written
        }
    } else {
        // oops - couldn't get data
    }
```